# Why don't scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr results agree with scipy.stats.pearsonr?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I expected that the results for scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr for masked array inputs would give the same results for scipy.stats.pearsonr for the **unmasked** values of the input data, but it doesn't:

```
from pylab import randn,rand
from numpy import ma
import scipy.stats

# Normally distributed data with noise
x=ma.masked_array(randn(10000),mask=False)
y=x+randn(10000)*0.6

# Randomly mask one tenth of each of x and y
x[rand(10000)<0.1]=ma.masked
y[rand(10000)<0.1]=ma.masked

# Identify indices for which both data are unmasked
bothok=((~x.mask)*(~y.mask))

# print results of both functions, passing only the data where 
# both x and y are good to scipy.stats
print "scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr:", scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr(x,y)[0]
print "scipy.stats.pearsonr:", scipy.stats.pearsonr(x[bothok].data,y[bothok].data)[0]
```

The answer will vary a little bit each time you do this, but the values differed by about 0.1 for me, and the bigger the masked fraction, the bigger the disagreement.

I noticed that if the same mask was used for both x and y, the results are the same for both functions, i.e.:

```
mask=rand(10000)<0.1
x[mask]=ma.masked
y[mask]=ma.masked
...
```

Is this a bug, or am I expected to precondition the input data to make sure the masks in both x and y are identical (surely not)?

I'm using numpy version '1.8.0' and scipy version '0.11.0b1'

Comment: Please note that this problem persists in Scipy '0.14.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr`.  It appears that the values in `x` and `y` are expected to be paired by index, so if one is masked, the other should be ignored.  That is, if `x` and `y` look like (using `--` for a masked value):

```
x = [1, --,  3,  4,  5]
y = [9,  8, --,  6,  5]
```

then both `(--, 8)` and `(3, --)` are to be ignored, and the result should should be the same as `scipy.stats.pearsonr([1, 4, 5], [9, 6, 5])`.

The bug in [the `mstats` version](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L351) is that the code to [compute the means of `x` and `y`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L360) does not use the common mask.

I created an issue for this on the scipy github site: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3645

Comment: I looked briefly in the documentation for how to modify the missing value handling, but it didn't really seem like there were any options. Wouldn't it be useful to have keyword arguments for all of these mstats functions?

Answer (score 1):

We have (at least) two options for missing value handling, complete case deletion and pairwise deletion.

In your use of `scipy.stats.pearsonr` you completely drop cases where there is a missing value in any of the variables.

`numpy.ma.corrcoef` gives the same results.

Checking the source of `scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr`, it doesn't do complete case deletion for the calculating the variance or the mean.

```
>>> xm = x - x.mean(0)
>>> ym = y - y.mean(0)
>>> np.ma.dot(xm, ym) / np.sqrt(np.ma.dot(xm, xm) * np.ma.dot(ym, ym))
0.7731167378113557

>>> scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr(x,y)[0]
0.77311673781135637
```

However, the difference between complete and pairwise case deletion on mean and standard deviations is small.

The main discrepancy seems to come from the missing correction for the different number of non-missing elements. Iignoring degrees of freedom corrections, I get

```
>>> np.ma.dot(xm, ym) / bothok.sum() / \
    np.sqrt(np.ma.dot(xm, xm) / (~xm.mask).sum() * np.ma.dot(ym, ym) / (~ym.mask).sum())
0.85855728319303393
```

which is close to the complete case deletion case.

Comment: I agree that we have those options and can return a statistically valid answer with both approaches, but it does not appear that we get to choose with scipy.stats.mstats.pearsonr, and the differences can be large.

Comment: `scipy.stats.mstats` has been partially neglected for a while for lack of contributors. The bugfix in the issue that Warren opened, is high-priority. Enhancements to make these functions more flexible rely on open source contributions by interested parties. Otherwise the pace for these improvements will depend on maintainer interest and priorities. Questions like this are still very helpful to identify the problems.